# TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to shorten a string in a react component I got from an API call in react but I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined.

here is the snippet:

```
shorten(){
    let res = this.props.details.substring(100, 0);
    return res;
}
```

I am using the function in a render return function as:

```
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="text-muted font1-1">{this.shorten()}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Error code:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

Comment: Your `details` prop has no value.

Comment: it has a value, I console logged to confirm.

Comment: You got the value from an API. So your value, in the beginning, is undefined. After when the API comes back, you got the value, and you saw this result in console, but the first time when react renders your component the `details` prop has no value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the shorten method and try this

```
render(){
    const shorten = this.props.details ? this.props.details.substring(0, 100) : '';
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="text-muted font1-1">{shorten}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the error happens just before the API call is made, use optional chaining (`?.`) to check whether the string to be truncated is available yet.

```
let res = this.props.details?.substring(100, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to console.log the value of shorten? Do you get undefined in the console too?

if so, is it possible that you are not waiting for the API value.

Are you familiar with the concept of promise ? 
My hypothesis is that you get undefined because you are trying to see the result without have some async/await in place (or some other way to wait for the promise to be resolved), which means that you are trying to read the value before it actually exist, that is why you get the undefined

Comment: the value from the console.log of the shorten value works as expected. Apparently I have to check for null value first. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that too, because of the React Lifecycle
The important thing is that you got the solution, have a nice day =)

Answer (score 1):

Add a null check before use `substring`, like this: `let res = this.props.details && this.props.details.substring(100,0);`

Comment: Thank you, now I know I have to check for null because of how React renders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the prop is pass probably there's some state of the parent that causes `this.props.details` to be undefined.

Ther are 3 solutions.

1. When you're passing the prop you can add a check

```
<YourComponent details={this.state.whatever || '' } />
```

2. you can check it inside the component

```
let res = this.props.details && this.props.details.substring(100, 0);
```

3. Don't render the component until all required props are passed and they're defined.

Comment: Thanks, I followed a similar solution.
Problem solved.